# Batch Script: Use a variable in a netsh command

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

in my batch script I want that the user makes three inputs: IP-Address, Mask, Gateway, so I can set up my ip config.

I decided to make it like this:

```
set /p v_ipadress="IP Adresse: "
set /p v_mask="Maske: "
set /p v_gate="Gateway: "

netsh interface ip set address name="WiFi" source=static addr=%v_ipadress% mask=%v_mask% gateway=%v_gate%
```

The problem is, it doesn't change my ip config. What is the problem? Can't the variable save it in the form: 192.168.178.1 ???

Greetings

Comment: Are you sure to run the script as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Modify the last line to
netsh interface ip set address name="WiFi" static %v_ipadress% %v_mask% %v_gate%

and make sure to run the script as administrator